# How to publish to pub/sub with just an api key

Tags: post, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to publish messages to GCP Pub/Sub with a POST request as the platform I'm using (Zoho) does not allow for any of the GCP libraries. I'm not sure how to make the request in a simple way, as the normal authentication system seems complex.

1. Is there an easy way to publish a message using, e.g., an API key?
2. Alternatively is there a simple way to create an API endpoint within GCP that I can then forward data on to the messaging system?

I have used the python client to publish to Pub/Sub, but cannot make POST requests because of the authentication issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your questions will have the same answer, yes, and Google Cloud Endpoints is your way to go here.

With Google Cloud Endpoints you can create a custom endpoint and use API keys to authenticate the requests that are being done. There's a really good how-to guide from [medium](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-pubsub-push-with-cloud-endpoints-6a1adc36db9f) you can follow in order to set up your endpoint and your Pub/Sub push subscription.

More information about creating push subscriptions can be found in the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-py-mac#quickstart_setup).

Comment: Ok awesome - given I want this Endpoint to sit in front of the topics api (i.e., to publish to topic), does this mean I need to spin up something to serve the API backend? Is there a way to do this in a 'serverless' sense?

Comment: Yes, Cloud Endpoints will serve as a proxy for your API, but you will still need to serve the backend. To do so, you have several options, you can deploy in [GAE, GCE or GKE](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/deploy-api-backend). [Here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-endpoints) you can also find a quickstart to Cloud Endpoints, in which both the Endpoint and the API backend are deployed.