# Google Cloud Pub/Sub - Endpoints config to publish with just an Api Key

Tags: post, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to publish messages to Google Cloud Pub/Sub without using OAuth or the Google SDK, but an Api Key instead
(Similar to ["how to publish to pub/sub with just an api key"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524669/how-to-publish-to-pub-sub-with-just-an-api-key)).

There is a guide on [medium](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-pubsub-push-with-cloud-endpoints-6a1adc36db9f) on how to secure Push Subscriptions,
but I could not figure out how to configure Endpoints in a way so I can send a pub/sub publish request with just an api key.

Could you please share a matching example Endpoints configuration (yaml file)?

Comment: I do not believe your objective to use an API key with Pub/Sub with Endpoints is possible today (or ever was). For most Google Cloud services, API keys are being dropped/not supported. You will need to use Service Accounts. As OAuth Identity is deployed on more and more services, this will become mandatory. Start planning today as this is already being deployed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you are referring to in your post is about how to secure the destination endpoint (Calling from Pub/Sub using the push subscription), not how to secure Pub/Sub itself from HTTP Request.

If you have the need to Call Pub/Sub without use OAuth (using API Key instead) unfortunately is not out of the box and you need to implement some pieces.

Referring to the official documentation: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/authentication
"Cloud Pub/Sub does not support API keys as an authentication method."

If you want to achieve this goal:

You need to create a Backend in front of Pub/Sub, put Cloud Endpoints (With an ESP https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/deploy-api-backend) in front of the Backend with API Key security configured in the openapi.yaml and from the Backend make a call to Pub/Sub.

HTTP Request -> Cloud Endpoint (ESP in Compute Engine, App Engine, GKE, etc) -> Backend (Compute Engine, App Engine, GKE, etc) -> Pub/Sub

You can review the documentation of Cloud Endpoints (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs) if you need more information about how to make the implementation.